# how to flexible an api to listen a variable in own url?

Tags: php, api, url, listener, whmcs

I want to felexible this whmcs internal api to listen id array from own url. (i.e. www.example.com/api.php?pid=2 ). any help please?

```
<?php
require_once('init.php');
$command = 'GetProducts';
$postData = array(
    'id' => '1',
);
$adminUsername = 'admin';

$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername);
print_r($results);
```

I have used below code but it's not successful.

```
<?php
require_once('init.php');
$command = 'GetProducts';
$prid = $_GET["pid"];
$postData = array(
    'id' => '.'echo $prid;'.',
);
$adminUsername = 'admin';

$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by `urlencode($pid)` instead of `$_GET["pid"]`.

```
<?php
require_once('init.php');
$command = 'GetProducts';
$postData = array(
    'pid' => urlencode($pid),
);
$adminUsername = 'admin';

$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername);
print_r($results);
```